How to divide SSR and CSR correctly in Next js?
I can't make page.tsx a server component because I use useState and onClick there.
'use client'
import axios from "axios";
import { ChangeEvent, FormEvent, useState } from "react";
import List from "./list/List";

export default function Home() {

  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  const [serverRes, setServerRes] = useState<string>("no action yet")

  const handleInputChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  const createUser = async (event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/create-user", name)
        .then(res => setServerRes(res.data.message))
    } catch (error) {
      setServerRes("" + error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={createUser}>
        <input onChange={handleInputChange} className="p-4 h-full border-2" type="text" placeholder="name" />
        <button className="p-4 bg-red-300">create user</button>
      </form>
      <div>Server log: {serverRes}</div>
      <h2>List of users</h2>
      <List />
    </>
  );
}


I tried to somehow divide one page into two components (one for server and one for client), but I couldn't find the way where it will work.
